# Enter values to correct table cell (according to entry of first column) in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a MATLAB array with R rows and C columns, where the first column contains numerical identifiers, which are not necessarily a set of ordered numbers.

Now, I load a second array with R' rows and 2 columns, where again the first column contains identifiers, while the second column contains numerical data. How can I efficiently write the data corresponding to identifier I into an additional column of the correspoding row (also identified by identifier I) of the original array?

Of course a trivial solution would be a construct of for loops and if-else or switch-case conditions, but I suppose there must be a more elegant, vectorized way to do it.

To further illustrate the problem:

```
A1 = [        %first array
      1, 0.3  
      2, 0.9
      3, 12];

A2 = [        %second array
      1, 0.5
      3, 9];

G = [         %goal
     1, 0.3, 0.5
     2, 0.9, NaN
     3, 12, 9];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
G = A1; % define G as A1
G(:,end+1) = NaN; % extend with a column of NaNs
[is, ind] = ismember(A2(:,1), A1(:,1)); % matchings of first column of A2 in A1,
                                        % and their indices
G(ind(is),end) = A2(is,2); % fill matched rows with values second column of A2
```

Note that:

- This also works if some identifier in `A2` is *not present* in `A1`.
- If several rows of `A2`  have the same identifier, the value corresponding to the *last* one gets written into `G`.

Comment: Works like a charm! ismember was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!